# Finding lengths of triangular pyramid sides

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

Given the triangular pyramid ABCD, where angles ABC, ACD, and BCD are right angles
If you know the angles BAC and DAC, and the length of the edge AD,

Can you determine the lengths of edges AC, BC, and CD? And if so, how?

[image: pyramid]

Comment: There is a typo in the text, $ACB$ is not a right angle, it should be $ABC$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we know $\angle DAC$ and the length of $AD$, then it's elementary trigonometry to find $AC$ and $CD$.

And now that we know $CD$ and $\angle BAC$, it's elementary trigonometry to find $AB$ and $BC$.

Finally, you can use the Pythagorean theorem to find $BD$.